# Rethinkdb race conditions creating table

Tags: node.js, docker, rethinkdb

I have an add written in nodejs which uses rethinkdb.  At startup time, the app does a bunch of database setup, including creating necessary tables if they do not exist.  The code (simplified) looks something like:

```
  r.tableList().run(conn).then(existingTables => 
    requiredTables
      .filter(t => existingTables.indexOf(t) === -1)
      .map(name => r.tableCreate(name).run(conn)));
```

This works fine.  The problem is that the app is running inside a docker container, and I need to be able to scale out using `docker-compose scale app=3`, for example. When the deploy job runs this, three new containers are immediately created, each of which creates a set of tables resulting in database issues which I need to resolve manually.  I think I can understand why this happens, but I can't see how to solve it.  I had thought of trying to write it all in a single query, but the real use is a quite a bit more complex (i.e. creates indexes, runs migrations, populates sample data) and I don't think there is any way I can do the lot in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB currently doesn't guarantee that administrative actions are atomic.  The best thing to do would probably be to separate out the administrative actions (creating databases, tables, and indexes) and run those in a separate setup step that runs in only one container.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that, but I really don't want to create a separate service just for that.  Also, bootstrapping would become tricky as I would need to wait for the db actions to run before starting the main app containers - as far as I know docker-compose has no support for that sort of chaining so I would need to script it manually.

Comment: You could maybe have the app containers wait for the db to be ready rather than waiting to launch them until it's ready.  (Also, if you don't want to create a separate service, another option would be to make your app services smart enough to resolve conflicting db/table names, e.g. by having them always delete the ones with the highest UUIDs when there's a conflict.  You could do that by looking at the relevant system table in the `rethinkdb` database.)